VSCode autoformat setting for HTML bracket wrapping
I must have changed something recently but I don't know what. The formatter has started doing this:
<a
    href="https://snakeriveradventures.com/stay-overnight-in-hells-canyon/"
    >Garden Creek Ranch</a
>

when I would prefer this:
<a href="https://snakeriveradventures.com/stay-overnight-in-hells-canyon/">
    Garden Creek Ranch
</a>

The only setting I have for HTML is:
    "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true

I don't see anything in the VSCode HTML formatting doc that looks like it explains this

Do you have other formatters installed like prettier?
